# Matcher.group() is returning a part of expected result .For ex a url "www.google.com" , my matcher is returning "www."

Tags: java, android, regex, url, kotlin

My requirement is to check a URL in a string using regex.
What I am doing is using Pattern and Matcher finding whether a string contains URL or not

```
 val pattern = Pattern.compile(HyperlinkParser.validRegex.toString())
    val matcher = pattern.matcher(htmlParsedMessage) //"abcd www.google.com def"
    while (matcher.find()) {
        val url = matcher.group()//contains the required url but it returns "www.".Expected "www.google.com"
        val indicesPair = Pair(matcher.start(), matcher.end())
        hyperlinkStartEndIndicesList.add(indicesPair)
    }
    matcher.reset()
```

Where `HyperlinkParser.validRegex`is

```
private const val regularExpression = "(?:(?:https?|ftp|file):|www.|ftp.)(?:([-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|\$?!:,.]*)|[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|\$?!:,.])*(?:([-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|\$?!:,.]*)|[A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|\$])"
val validRegex = Regex(regularExpression,RegexOption.IGNORE_CASE)
```

I am expecting the URL "www.google.com" but it is returning "www.".

Any ideas what can be the issue. Any help would be greatly accepted.

Comment: So whats the Problem?) You did not stated any problems, just explained what you are doing.

Comment: As I commented in the snippet above. I am expecting the URL "www.google.com" but it is returning "www.".

Comment: Are you sure the issue is related to the code you posted? The regex is not great, but the whole match is `www.google.com` and you use `matcher.find()` and then `matcher.start(), matcher.end()` that provide the details about the whole match positions (no idea why you do not use `matcher.group()` directly, is there any reason?), so that should work

Comment: Yes , it is related to my code. matcher.group is just for simplicity that it returns a group.matcher.start() and matcher.end() is returning 0,4 respectively expected results were 0,14.No matter what it returns the same if I  use substring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **documentation** of the [`toString()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex/to-string.html) method of [`Regex`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex/index.html):

> Returns the string representation of this regular expression, namely the [pattern](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex/pattern.html#kotlin.text.Regex$pattern) of this regular expression.
>
> Note that another regular expression constructed from the same pattern string may have different [options](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex/options.html#kotlin.text.Regex$options) and may match strings differently.

Which means that it is the same as the `regularExpression` string **without the `IGNORE_CASE` option**.

So when you do `val pattern = Pattern.compile(HyperlinkParser.validRegex.toString())`, you lose the case-insensitive option, and that's why `google.com` isn't matched, since your regex only matches `A-Z`.

Change that line to:

```
val pattern = HyperlinkParser.validRegex.toPattern()
```

That will work, because the **documentation** of `toPattern` says:

> Returns an instance of [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) with the **same pattern string *and* options** as this instance of [Regex](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex/index.html) has.
>
> Provides the way to use [Regex](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex/index.html) where [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) is required.

Comment: I am facing another issue which is . Whenever I am adding an invalid url for ex(http:www.google.com) I am getting this as a valid url and the group which matcher is returning is "www.google.com" . Any ideas why?

Comment: @sandeepdhami Why would you expect `http:www.google.com` not to match, when the regex specifically says to match `http:` prefix followed by sequence of valid characters? --- Anyway, if you have a problem with the regex itself, you should create a new question and ask about it.